# Which is faster? Searching through a file or a container that can handle multiple keys and values (if there is any)

Tags: c++, file, containers, processing-efficiency

I am trying to load data from an OpenStreetMap file into the program. I thought of just searching through a ["filtered" file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/powerover9001/justFiles/main/testnodes.txt) that already separated the necessary data, or I can load the "filtered" data into a container in C++ to search it from there (not counting loading into container time, just search time).

Which one is faster?
And is there a container that can store multiple keys and values in insertion order?

Comment: RAM is orders of magnitude faster then disk storage.  Line get a little blurrier when you have things like optane, but in general it holds.

Comment: Also depends on what you are going to search for? Are you doing more than one search per file? Then you want to parse it only once, for sure.

Comment: Perhaps this is the container you are looking for: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap

Comment: You could memory map the file, if your OS supports it, which may speed up reading the file.

Comment: Remember, there is an overhead for every file transaction.  You'll want to read as much data as you can per transaction to reduce the overall overhead.